# React-Native enable hot reload on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I would like enable hot reload on my iOS device. I've only **reload**, **Debug JS Remotely**, **Toggle Inspector**, **Show Perf Monitor**, **Cancel**.

Do you know if i can enable hot/live reload ?

I've edit my **AppDelegate.m** and add my ip, but no result.

If i push **Debug Remotely**, the device search localhost :/

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Which version of react-native is your project using? IOS version? Are your development machine and mobile connected to the same network?

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that the failure to connect to the packager on the host machine fails silently in newer versions of React Native. This tends to occur when the host machine and the physical device are connected to different WLANs. The developer menu only shows the options listed in your question in those cases. The described behaviour occurs at least on RN v0.50.4 and with the following declaration in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@“index” fallbackResource:nil];
```

The device uses a pre-bundled file in those circumstances.

---

TL;DR confirm that the iOS device is connected to the same wireless network as the host machine.

Comment: @StéphaneRICHIN Are you saying that you are seeing this behaviour even though both the host machine and the iOS device are connected to the same network? Or are you saying something else?

Comment: Yes sorry, I've this problem only on iOS emulator :) for this time, no error on my device

Comment: I haven't stumbled upon this error on a simulator, sorry. I'd just advice you to check that your AppDelegate.m approximately matches [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/ios/HelloWorld/AppDelegate.m), and that other configurations match what is produced by `react-native init`.